# How to display progress bar while inserting multiple records to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using php and MySQL to insert 50k data at a time within loop,
i want to show progress bar which display number of record inserted like 
1000 record inserted,2000 record inserted,5000 record inserted like this.
I am trying this code. but its not working.
Please help anyone.

```
/////////////////progressbar.php///////////////////

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script> 
    function prbar(){

    $("#pr").load("getSession.php");

    tmout=setTimeout(prbar,2000);
    } 
    $.ajax({
    url:"ajax.php",
    type:'get',
    datatype:'json',
    data:"st=str",

    success:function(data){
    clearTimeout(tmout);
    alert(data);
    },
    error:function(){
    alert("error");
    }
    });
    prbar(); 
    </script>
    <html>
    <body>
   <div id="pr"> Processing.... </div>
    </body>
    </html>



     ////////////// ajax.php/////////////////

    session_start(); 
    for($i=1;$i<=50000;$i++){ 
    mysql_insert("")// insert query
    $_SESSION['vl']=$i;
    session_write_close();
    }

    ?>

//////////////getSession.php/////////////////

    <?php
    session_start();
    echo "$_SESSION[vl] Number Inserted !";
    ?>
```

Comment: There have no solution for my question.

Comment: You can make another AJAX call and get the number of rows. Call this function every 5-10 seconds and you done!

Comment: I am inserting data so how it possible to get number of row